# How to set Border.BorderBrush from string

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, brush

Theres a problem. I can't set the BorderBrush using a string value per C#-Code (not in XAML):

```
 ((Border)((Image)sender).Parent).BorderBrush = "#FFBCC7D8";
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must use an Converter to convert the string to a Brush-Object. In the Framework there is a [BrushConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushconverter.aspx) to do this.

```
BrushConverter converter = new BrushConverter();
BorderBrush brush = converter.ConvertFromString("#FFBCC7D8") as Brush;
((Border)((Image)sender).Parent).BorderBrush = brush;
```